# Python - finding TTF files

Tags: python, truetype

Can anyone improve on this? I'm fairly new to python and am trying to write portable code. I need to locate a font file to pass to ImageDraw.Draw.Text.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fontman

def findFontFile(searchFont):
    fList = fontman.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
    targetFont = []
    for row in fList:
        try:
            if searchFont in row:
                targetFont.append(row)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return targetFont[0]
```

On my system this gives me:

```
>>> findFontFile('DejaVuSans.ttf')
'/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf'
```

Which is exactly what I need. Does this look like it will work on Mac / Windows systems as well as Linux (tested on Linux)? Could it be done more efficiently? In a more readable style? Will Mac / Windows have a different font file naming format? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html) it says it supports several platforms. I think you could spend a while trying to find out what platforms it is supposed to work on.

None of your code seems to be in any way platform-dependent so it all depends on matplotlib.

Also, if any font is good for you, you could `return row`.

Comment: why did you not use matplotlib.font_manager.FontManager?

Comment: Because I hadn't read the full documentation. I've marked Cristiano's answer, but I'll probably go with FontManager instead. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a little rewrite like (some changes are just a matter of style, more python like):

```
   def find_font_file(query):
       matches = list(filter(lambda path: query in os.path.basename(path), fontman.findSystemFonts()))
       return matches
```

The caller would then decide the element to use (after checking permissions etc).

As for the compatibility you can view [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py) that the lib uses a set of common directories for the "main" operating systems to search for fonts (X window manager (linux), windows and os x). But you can always pass the directories where you want to search if you have more information on the different environments where the app is going to run.

Comment: Changed to follow @lieryan advice

Comment: On Python3, filter is not working. But the reference to fontman was great.

Answer (score 0):

be careful when doing `if searchFont in row`.

If someone has username is marial, and you're searching for the font arial, by using `findFontFile('arial')`, your code would be getting all of the fonts installed in the user's home directory (i.e. /home/marial/.fonts).